# Schengen visa-waiver. Travel from Canada

Tags: schengen-visas

I am reading about a schengen visa waiver existing, but some people say that it hasn't started yet and starts later in the year.
The official sites say that there is no visa requirement for Canadians but don't mention if a visa waiver is or isn't needed. Some say you need a visa. Do visa waivers exist or is it a scam?

Comment: To confirm, are you a Canadian citizen?

Comment: yes, that is correct

Comment: This is likely a duplicate question, now looking for the other one. But in short, the Electronic registration system has not started yet, Canadian citizens do not need a visa now. Supposed to start in 2024, but it has been postponed before.

Comment: Perfect, thanks